# Error While Running Nodemon Server

Tags: express, nodemon

When i try to run my file with nodemon src/app.js I get this error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1008:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1031:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1253:14)
    at listen (net.js:1289:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1385:5)
    at EventEmitter.listen (/Users/kevinmcnamara/express-dill/dill-    website/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:617:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kevinmcnamara/express-dill/dill-website/src/app.js:21:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have tried running ps -w | grep node then running the kill command with the PID number I get running the previous command, but it returns a message saying - No such process.

Does anyone have any advice to get my express server running again?

Comment: Have you tried another port? Perhaps a daemon is using port 3000 already...

Comment: You could also try **killall node**

Comment: I tried using port 3001 and it worked. killall node did not work. I am still curious as to what is happening with port 3000 and why it is in use. I started getting this error when I began using nodemon with node-inspector. Using these two together, I was running nodemon --debug src/app.js in one terminal tab, and node-inspector in the other.